# Setting enable_keep_alive to "yes" is causing Mongoose server to hang

Tags: mongoose-web-server

I tried to use keep-alive connection in mongoose and noticed it is sometimes hanging.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Got a reply from mongoose google code issue list. http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/issues/detail?id=277#c1